# Open new window with Javascript window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to open a new window when a form is submitted, I have the following code:

```
var action = window.open("http://myurl.com" + code + "&rp=" + window.rp + "23-421B-A4A2-";)

$('#theForm').attr("action", action);
```

However that causes an error, how do I append window.open correctly? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? Please be specific.

Comment: the form action is a URL, not a JS function.  You need an onsubmit handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Using "action" + "target=_blank"

   ```
   var action = "http://myurl.com" + code + "&rp=" + window.rp + "23-421B-A4A2-";
   $("#theForm").attr("action", action).atrr("target", "_blank");
   ```
2. Using "onsubmit" event

   ```
   $("#theForm").on("submit", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       window.open("http://myurl.com" + code + "&rp=" + window.rp + "23-421B-A4A2-");
   }
   ```

EDIT:

After you showing your HTML, there are other problems there:

- You're not using a submit button, you're using a image input instead.
- You have this code in your JS:

  ```
  $('#submit').click(function($e) {
      $e.preventDefault(); //Don't want button submitting the form because the action is not correct
      if (window.console) console.log($('#theForm').attr("action"));
      window.parent.location = ($('#theForm').attr("action"));
  });
  ```
- So, you need to modify this code to (or something like that):

  ```
  $('#submit').click(function($e) {
      $e.preventDefault(); //Don't want button submitting the form because the action is not correct
      if (window.console) console.log($('#theForm').attr("action"));
      window.open($('#theForm').attr("action"));
  });
  ```

Comment: I tried "action" + "target=_blank" earlier but no luck, the "onsubmit"  event doesn't seem to either

Comment: Show us your HTML, then.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
$('#theForm').click(function(event) { // or $('#theForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open("http://myurl.com" + code + "&rp=" + window.rp + "23-421B-A4A2-", windowHandle);
});
```

More info on [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).

Comment: I think you mean "submit", not "click".

Comment: Without the HTML it's just guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

this should be something like:

```
<form id="theForm" action="http://myurl.com/.../...?..." target="_blank"></form>
```